# Can anyone help me processing data with Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

So I have a list of DataFrame:

```
list_table = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g]
```

I wanted to drop `"Unnamed: 36"` column from each DataFrame and change the data type to numeric and I also wanted to make a new column which is gain from the sum of each row named `'Total'`.

Here's my `to_numeric` function:

```
def to_numeric(df):
    col = df.columns

    for i in range(len(col)):
        df[col[i]] = pd.to_numeric(
            df[col[i]].fillna(0).apply(
                lambda x: str(x).replace(",", "")
            )
        )

    return df
```

My for loop to do the processing:

```
for newtable in list_table:
    newtable = newtable.drop("Unnamed: 36", axis=1)
    newtable = to_numeric(newtable)
    newtable['Total'] = newtable.sum(axis=1)
    newtable.index = pd.to_datetime(newtable.index)
```

But after processing the loop, each DataFrame wasn't changed so I'm a bit confused to do this. Anyone can help me with this problem?

Comment: Those methods probably do not make changes *in-place* - consult the documentation [https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html)

Comment: When you use the variable `a` or `d` do you expect to see those changes?

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually update your dataframes inside your list. You must apply all these changes on your list elements and one way to do this is by using a function. See below:

```
def change(newtable):
    newtable = newtable.drop("Unnamed: 36", axis=1)
    newtable = to_numeric(newtable)
    newtable['Total'] = newtable.sum(axis=1)
    newtable.index = pd.to_datetime(newtable.index)
    return newtable

result=[change(i) for i in list_table]
```

Alternatively, you can loop through the index of list_table and update the items like below:

```
for i in range(len(list_table)):
    newtable=list_table[i]
    newtable = newtable.drop("Unnamed: 36", axis=1)
    newtable = to_numeric(newtable)
    newtable['Total'] = newtable.sum(axis=1)
    newtable.index = pd.to_datetime(newtable.index)
    list_table[i]=newtable
```

Comment: Will the OP see that change in the DataFrame assigned to the name `a`?

Comment: I don't think that list_table items are actually 'a', 'b' etc most possibly these are pure dataframes. You cannot append a 'name of dataframe' to a list that represents the dataframe, you can only append the dataframe itself

Comment: You could achieve that, if needed, by adding another line: `a,b,c,d,e,f,g = result`.